# How to print Book class values to another Cart class?

Tags: java

I am having trouble printing the values inside of the Book class to my Cart Class. I tried calling the `Book book = new Book();` doesn't work because I didn't put anything since I am not suppose to since it is not the Main class. I try `Book.toString();` also doesn't work. What I am trying to do is that I I insert 1 as my itemNum my Book values are display and if I insert 2 then my Dictionary values is display. But I cannot seem to solve this problem. Any solutions of how I can print my values from Book to my Cart class?

Book Class:

```
public class Book{
    private String author;
    private int numPages;

    public Book(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String author, int numPages){
        this.author = author;
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getAuthor(){
        return this.author;
    }
    public int getNumPages(){
        return this.numPages;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }
    public void setNumPages(int numPages){
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    //toString
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String outputBookDes = "";
        outputBookDes += "Author: "+ this.author;
        outputBookDes += "Number Pages: "+ this.numPages;
        return outputBookDes;
    }
}
```

Cart Class:

```
public class Cart {
    private SaleItem[] itemList;
    private int numItems;

    public Cart(int numItems){
        itemList = new SaleItem[numItems];
    }

    public void addItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, int itemNum){

        if (itemNum == 1){
            System.out.println(Book.getAuthor());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `Book.getAuthor()` gets a compiler error since `getAuthor()` is not a static method. You need a Book attribute for Cart class where you are going to storage the data and then displayed in `addItem()`method.

For example:

```
public class Cart{
  private Book book;
  ...

  public void setBook (Book book){
      this.book = book;
  }      

  public Cart (int numItems){
     //Initialize the class attributes
     book = new Book();
     itemList = new SaleItem[numItems];
  }

  public void addItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, int itemNum){

     if (itemNum == 1){
         System.out.println(book.getAuthor());
     }
  }
}
```

Use `setBook()` to set the values for book before calling `addItem()` or put it inside `addItem()`. If you want to storage more than one Book, you will need an array of Books.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.